# Hue on Cloudera - NULL values (importing file)

Tags: hive, cloudera, hue

Yesterday I installed Cloudera QuickStart VM 5.8. After the import operation of files from the database by HUE, in some tables there were a NULL value (the entire column). In previous steps data display them properly as they should be imported.

[First Pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLG6O.png)
[Second Pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05M72.png)

Answer (score 0):

can you run the command describe formatted table_name in hive shell and see what is the field delimiter and then go to the warehouse directory and see if the delimiter in the data and in the table definition is same.i am sure it will not be same thats  why you see null.

i am assuming you have imported the data in the default warehouse directory.

then you can do one of the following

1) delete your hive table and create it again with correct delimiter as it is in the actual data ( row format delimited fields terminated by "your delimitor" and give location as your data file

or

2) delete the data that is imported and run sqoop import again and give the fields-terminated-by " the delimitor in the hive table definition"

Comment: I have still the same problem, i checked delimiters and in hive and metastore manager are the same. I tried also create table via hive cmd and load data from local, but with no change.

Comment: I may add that in File Browser it looks as it should.

Comment: could you please copy paste the output of your describe formated  on hive shell and the sample data in your file.

Comment: Here's settings from Hive shell and my file (sorry i haven't enough time to copy-paste it from my machine, i haven't network there): http://imgur.com/a/XeO1X

Comment: It's not in the same dir, because i copied it to hadoop by command _hadoop fs -copyFromLocal etc._

Answer (score 0):

Once check datatype of second(col_1) and third(col_2) in original database from where your exporting.
This can not be case of missing delimiter, else fourth(col_3) would not have populated correctly, which is correct.

Comment: yes ashish you seems to be correct..i did not check the screen shots.